# is there a reason why the alert box text after course isn't be put in the alert box?

Tags: javascript

This is the alert box I made within the google chrome developer console, I'm a beginner following along with a course and I'm confused as to why none of the text after the word course is being displayed in the alert box.

```
alert(" Welcome " + myName + " to the javascript basics course ", " I'm your tutor ", + yourName + "!" );
```

Comment: what is ", " (after "course") supposed to accomplish? A line break? try "course \nI'm your tutor". Use "+" to concatenate strings, also with  ... tutor " + yourName + "!" (without the comma)

Comment: Seems to have solved it thanks and the comma was intentional I just had it in the wrong spot lol

Answer (score 2):

You've got a comma in there which makes it so that you are passing 2 arguments to the `alert` function, when in reality `alert` only accepts 1 argument. So therefor the 2nd argument (containing "I'm your tutor....") is being ignored.

You have 2 options:

**Option 1:**

Remove the comma so that 1 argument is passed to `alert`:

```js
alert("Welcome " + myName + " to the javascript basics course, I'm your tutor " + yourName + "!");
```

**Option 2 (Better):**

Use template strings instead of concatenation:

```js
alert(`Welcome ${myName} to the javascript basics course, I'm your tutor ${yourName}!`);
```